# Issue with writing files from Spark to CosmosDB

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb

I am currently learning cosmosDB in Azure environment. I am trying to establish connection to CosmosDB to write Json files from spark to cosmosDB.

---

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._ 
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config

val b=spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("wasb://somefolder@storage.blob.core.windows.net/hdp/file.json")
val c=b.registerTempTable("sathya")
val d=spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from sathya")

val writeConfigMap = Map(
"Endpoint" -> "https://somepoint.documents.azure.com:443/",
"Masterkey" -> 
"somekey,
"Database" -> "newdbcosmos",
"Collection" -> "newcollcosmos", 
"preferredRegions" -> "US East",
"SamplingRatio" -> "1.0",
"schema_samplesize" -> "200000"
)
```

Error while writing to CosmosDB:

```
scala> d.write.cosmosDB(writeConfigMap)
<console>:41: error: type mismatch;
**found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
required: com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
d.write.cosmosDB(writeConfigMap)**
```

I have read the docs in internet and I have uploaded the uber jar for cosmosDB connector. Anyone came across this issue and share the solution.

Thanks
Sathya

Comment: Is this still an outstanding issue? Which Cosmos DB API are you attempting to connect to? Providing a doc that might be helpful with this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/spark-connector-for-cosmosdb-seamless-interaction-with-globally-distributed-multi-model-data/ Also suggest that you obfuscate or delete your Masterkey value, as anyone can connect with a valid key value.

Comment: You left your folder, endpoint, key user details in your question. I have edited them out. You should pseudo name them before posting.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the prior revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Please set cosmos configuration in following way:

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
val cmosConfig = Config(Map(
    "Endpoint" -> "https://your_endpoint.documents.azure.com:443/",
    "Masterkey" -> 
    "your_key",
    "Database" -> "newdbcosmos",
    "Collection" -> "newcollcosmos", 
    "preferredRegions" -> "US East",
    "SamplingRatio" -> "1.0",
    "schema_samplesize" -> "200000"))
```

Comment: Thanks Vikash. My question is a different one but thanks for your response.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about your issue, from the question it seems like that you were unable to write to cosmos with given cosmos config (i.e. immutable map). I resolved the same error by using "Config(Map(...))".

Comment: @VikashPareek When i try to connect from data bricks it gives this error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON String: '' what might be the issue